# How to get user's id from auth0 in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, auth0

I recently implemented user authentication in my react web app using Auth0. And I need to retrieve some information from `user` object. I did this so far:

```
cost { user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
<p>{user.name}</p>
```

But I also want to get user's id, so I can reference them later in my backend. So I did this:

```
const { user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
<p>{user.user_id}</p>
```

And when I go to the website I get `undefined` instead of the user's id.

Is it happening because I use dev-keys for my social connections, or maybe it has to be done differently?

Comment: I assume `useAuth0` is a function that needs to be called `useAuth0()`? https://useauth.dev/docs/auth0/

Comment: Yeah, that's right, it was my fault writing this question, but in my code it's passed correctly, so it's not case.

Comment: Did you try `console.log(user)`?

Comment: can this help you? [Show User Profile Information](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login#show-user-profile-information)

Comment: Yes, and there is no user_id parameter, but in auth0 docs they say that you can retrieve it from there.

Comment: Yes I have seen that, but it's not very helpful.

Comment: Could you tell me what you tried?

Comment: Did you also try `console.log(user.id)`?

Comment: @Pirogrammer Yes, and I also got `undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229982/discussion-between-pirogrammer-and-jakub-klimek).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you are still searching for this problem, however I had a similar problem and found this as a solution:

```
const { user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
<p>{user.sub}</p>
```

source: https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-get-user-id-of-a-user-after-login-in-react-hook-useauth0/53309

Comment: I’m sorry, but the asker has already done this in the question.

Comment: I don't see where? I might miss a piece of information but asker only tried user.user_id and not 'user.sub'

Comment: @JakubKlimek Can you confirm if this answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

It should be the "sub" key. Discord id is 18 characters long. The results prefix it with oauth2|discord|. Which you can truncate out with a function.

```
const { user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
console.log(user.sub);
```

The results should be something like:

oauth2|discord|111111111111111111